# Replace space with an underscore

Tags: c++, removing-whitespace

I am trying to write something that will replace all the spaces in a string with an underscore.

What I have so far.

```
string space2underscore(string text)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            text[i] = '_';
    }
    return text;
}
```

For the most part this would work, if I was doing something like.

```
string word = "hello stackoverflow";
word = space2underscore(word);
cout << word;
```

That would output "hello_stackoverflow", which is just what I want.

However if I was to do something like

```
string word;
cin >> word;
word = space2underscore(word);
cout << word;
```

I would just get the first word, "hello".

Does anybody know a fix for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `cin >> word` is only going to read in the first word. If you want to operate on a whole like at a time, you should use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).

For example:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
s = space2underscore(s);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Also, you may want to check that you actually were able to read a line. You can do that like this:

```
std::string s;
if(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
    s = space2underscore(s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

---

Finally, as a side note, you could probably write your function in a cleaner way. Personally I would write it like this:

```
std::string space2underscore(std::string text) {
    for(std::string::iterator it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); ++it) {
        if(*it == ' ') {
            *it = '_';
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Or for bonus points, use [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)!

**EDIT:**
If you happen to be lucky enough to be able to use c++0x features (and I know that's a big if) you could use lambdas and `std::transform`, which results in some very simple code:

```
std::string s = "hello stackoverflow";
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char ch) {
    return ch == ' ' ? '_' : ch;
});
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but you're mixing up whether or not you use `std::` or not. (Though technically, your code works with `using std::cout;` at the top)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: you are right, personally I like to use an explicit `std::` but I copied some of the OP's code in my example. I'll clean that up.

Comment: Thank you sir!  My program runs fine now :)

Comment: I really, really like lambdas but in this case `std::replace` may be a better fit.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I have to be honest, I completely forgot about `std::replace`, good call!

Comment: @Evan Teran: Whenever I find myself writing yet another `for` loop I like to check the standard library. There is usually something there that is correct, fast, and with a more meaningful name than `for` or `while`. The less code I have to write means fewer bugs, too.

Answer (score 28):

You've got your `getline` issue fixed but I just wanted to say the Standard Library contains a lot of useful functions. Instead of a hand-rolled loop you could do:

```
std::string space2underscore(std::string text)
{
    std::replace(text.begin(), text.end(), ' ', '_');
    return text;
}
```

This works, it's fast, and it actually expresses what you are doing.

Comment: don't forget to mention that this needs **<algorithm>** header file to be included in your project.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your understanding of `std::cin` from the `iostream` library: Using the `>>` operator on a stream with an `std::string` as the right-hand-side argument only takes one word at a time (using whitespace to separate).

What you want instead is to use [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to get your string.

Answer (score 2):

For a modern C++1x approach you have the option of [std::regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace).

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::regex;
using std::string;
using std::regex_replace;

int main( const int, const char** )
{
   const auto target = regex{ " " };
   const auto replacement = string{ "_" };
   const auto value = string{ "hello stackoverflow" };

   cout << regex_replace( value, target, replacement ) << endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Pros**: Less code.

**Cons**: Regular expressions can cloud intent.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
cin >> word;
```

With

```
getline(cin, word);
```